# Use button to call a file.py with glade

Tags: python-3.x, pygtk, glade, pygobject

i'm trying through a python script in conjunction with glade, create a button that opens me a file in python so I can edit if I want to make some changes later. Can anyone help me if you please ?

What i did was this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GObject as gobject
import pygtk
import gtk


def show_script(button):
   dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open...", None, gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL, gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))

   dialog.set_default_response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)

   filter = gtk.FilerFilter()
   filter.set_name("All files")
   filter.add_pattern("*")
   dialog.add_filter(filter)

   response = dialog.run()
   if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
      print (dialog.get_filename(), 'selected')
   elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL:
      print  ('Closed, you didnt choose any files')
   dialog.destroy()


builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("Wi_Green_Sheddule_v1.glade")
handlers = {
      "action_show_script": show_script
   }
}

builder.connect_signals(handlers)
window = builder.get_object("window")
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

The error that my program does when i click the button is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/showShedduleWiGreen.py", line 70, in show_script
    dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open...", None, gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL, gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(_static_binding_error)
AttributeError: When using gi.repository you must not import static modules like "gobject". Please change all occurrences of "import gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject". See: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709183
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you are mixing up Python2 and Python3, and modules from introspection and older non-introspection modules:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GObject as gobject
import pygtk
import gtk
```

You are importing Gtk and gtk, which are not mixable. You also don't use GObject in your code, so don't import it.

Leave just

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

and change all 'gtk's in your code to Gtk.

Then, take care of the indenting - else you'll still have errors. And I couldn't test anymore, as the glade file is not included...